# How to iterate over the entire rows of the dataset and fill the additional column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, for-loop, pandas-groupby

I am beginner of python. I want to iterate over the entire rows of the dataset and fill the below columns appropriately. I need to use a for loop that starts from the first line of the dataset and do the same process in all of the lines. Could You give me enough instruction to write code by using for loop

```
date
#0  2016-01-01 05:00:00
#1  2016-01-01 06:00:00
#2  2016-01-01 07:00:00
#3  2016-01-01 08:00:00
#4  2016-01-01 09:00:00
#5  2016-01-01 10:00:00
#6  2016-01-01 11:00:00
#7  2016-01-01 12:00:00
#8  2016-01-01 13:00:00
#9  2016-01-01 14:00:00
#10 2016-01-01 15:00:00
#11 2016-01-01 16:00:00
#12 2016-01-01 17:00:00
#13 2016-01-01 18:00:00
#14 2016-01-01 19:00:00
#15 2016-01-01 20:00:00
#16 2016-01-01 21:00:00
#17 2016-01-01 22:00:00
#18 2016-01-01 23:00:00
#19 2016-01-02 00:00:00
#20 2016-01-02 01:00:00
#21 2016-01-02 02:00:00
#22 2016-01-02 03:00:00
#23 2016-01-02 04:00:00
#24 2016-01-02 05:00:00
#25 2016-01-02 06:00:00
#26 2016-01-02 07:00:00
#27 2016-01-02 08:00:00
#28 2016-01-02 09:00:00
#29 2016-01-02 10:00:00
#30 2016-01-02 11:00:00
#31 2016-01-02 12:00:00
#32 2016-01-02 13:00:00
#33 2016-01-02 14:00:00
#34 2016-01-02 15:00:00
#35 2016-01-02 16:00:00
#36 2016-01-02 17:00:00
#37 2016-01-02 18:00:00
#38 2016-01-02 19:00:00
#39 2016-01-02 20:00:00
#40 2016-01-02 21:00:00
#41 2016-01-02 22:00:00
#42 2016-01-02 23:00:00
#43 2016-01-03 00:00:00
#44 2016-01-03 01:00:00
#45 2016-01-03 02:00:00
#46 2016-01-03 03:00:00
#47 2016-01-03 04:00:00
#48 2016-01-03 05:00:00
#49 2016-01-03 06:00:00
#50 2016-01-03 07:00:00
#51 2016-01-03 08:00:00
#52 2016-01-03 09:00:00
#53 2016-01-03 10:00:00
#54 2016-01-03 11:00:00
#55 2016-01-03 12:00:00
#56 2016-01-03 13:00:00
#57 2016-01-03 14:00:00
#58 2016-01-03 15:00:00
#59 2016-01-03 16:00:00
#60 2016-01-03 17:00:00
#61 2016-01-03 18:00:00
#62 2016-01-03 19:00:00
#63 2016-01-03 20:00:00
#64 2016-01-03 21:00:00
#65 2016-01-03 22:00:00
#66 2016-01-03 23:00:00



 #Column name
    #day1
    #day2
    #day3
    #day4
    #day5
    #day6
    #day7

    i=0
    date_cell = dataset['date'][i]

    day_cell = date_cell.dayofweek
    dataset.iloc[i,day_cell] = 1
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please check out [ask] and do some research. Specifically, could you clarify: you wish to have a pandas dataframe with a 'date' column? where does this data come from? in which format is it available to you?

Comment: Thanks for your kind response. Yes, this is pandas datagram and the column 'date' is included within this dataset. After that, I additionally added 7 column which is day1, da2, day3 so on.

Comment: @Mr.Asif do you always need the 7 columns regardless of the days used? For instance... your example there only actually has 3 days...

Comment: yes. But my date column is so large. like 8398 rows. For this reason, I am not mentioned here full column

Answer (score 1):

You don't need / want to be using a for loop here, instead you can use `get_dummies` and join the result back to your original dataframe, eg:

Starting with:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('2016-01-01 05:00:00', end='2016-01-03 23:00:00', freq='1H')})
```

Apply `pd.get_dummies` on the `dayofweek` datetime accessor and re-index columns to make sure all 7 days are present as columns regardless of whether that day is actually in your dates, fill in anything missing with 0, add a prefix to the column names and join back to your original DF:

```
new_df = df.join(
    pd.get_dummies(df['date'].dt.dayofweek + 1)
    .reindex(range(1, 8), axis=1, fill_value=0)
    .add_prefix('day')
)
```

Gives you:

```
                  date  day1  day2  day3  day4  day5  day6  day7
0  2016-01-01 05:00:00     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
1  2016-01-01 06:00:00     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
2  2016-01-01 07:00:00     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
3  2016-01-01 08:00:00     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
4  2016-01-01 09:00:00     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
..                 ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...
62 2016-01-03 19:00:00     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
63 2016-01-03 20:00:00     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
64 2016-01-03 21:00:00     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
65 2016-01-03 22:00:00     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
66 2016-01-03 23:00:00     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
```

If you absolutely must use a for-loop (**not recommended**), then you can initialise your columns to 0  in one loop, then loop over the date column and update that row's day column to 1 for that day of the week, eg:

```
for n in range(1, 8):
    df.loc[:, f'day{n}'] = 0
for idx, date in df['date'].iteritems():
    df.loc[idx, f'day{date.dayofweek + 1}'] = 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Thanks for your kind response. 

but if I want to work with for loop so what should I have to do ?

Comment: @Mr.Asif is there any particular reason you're adamant on a for-loop? It's definitely not needed and very much an anti-pandas idiom...

Comment: Actually I want to learn. That's why I am very interested in it by for_loop. Could You help me to learn this?

Comment: Are you familiar with for-loops in general? As if not I'd suggesting learning without pandas as it's really really bad practice to do so in practice... you'd be learning an incorrect approach to the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @Mr.Asif updated to include for-loops... just don't use it in any serious code :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir. This is very kind of You

Comment: Anoter thing I want to know that, 

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('2016-01-01 05:00:00', end='2016-01-03 23:00:00', freq='1H')}) 

after writing this command in my dataset shows only the date column.  So there is anything else to show my full dataset column including date column?

Comment: Errr... that's just to create a sample dataset to show input/output... if you've already got `df` with things in it then you use that one

Comment: But without this line I am unable to find my output 

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('2016-01-01 05:00:00', end='2016-01-03 23:00:00', freq='1H')})

Either I use this line then I do not find my other column in my dataset

Comment: @Mr.Asif I'm not following... whatever you did to get your original `df` - run it again and don't use the above line to bind `df` to something else...

Comment: without above line I am unable to find the output

Comment: @Mr.Asif I'm afraid you're going to have to be much clearer what you mean and what you're doing...

Comment: #import pandas as pd 
#df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('2016-01-01 05:00:00', end='2016-01-03 23:00:00', freq='1H')}) 
#new_df = df.join( pd.get_dummies(df['date'].dt.dayofweek + 1) .reindex(range(1, 8), axis=1, fill_value=0) .add_prefix('day') ) 

#Whenever I use this code I get output but is shows only day1 to day7 column in the data frame within spyder. For kind information, I have a total of 35 columns. But it shows only 7 columns result